# Adding hours using momentJS seems to break after 12:00

Tags: javascript, angular, time, momentjs

Im trying to add a certain amount of hours to any given time. Lets say i have the time 04:00 and i add 12.0h. i want to get 16:00.

Im trying to achieve this using momentJS `add` and `subtract` methods, and it works, but only up to 12h.
Some examples to illustrate the problem:

- If i have 04:00 and i add 12h, i get 04:00.
- If i have 10:00 and i add 3h i get 01:00
- if i have 12:00 and i add 1h i get 01:00
- if i have 11:00 and i add 1h i get 12:00

Code:

```
const res = moment.utc('04:00', 'hh:mm').add(12, 'hours').format('hh:mm');
```

I expect the above to log 16:00, not 04:00

thanks for anyones help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are using a format string `hh:mm` with lowercase letters. That makes moment spit out 12 hour format. If you want 24 hour format the letters should be in uppercase `HH:mm`. If you were to add an a to the end of your format string you would find that it would label it as 4:00pm (`hh:mm a`).

[here's a demo](https://repl.it/repls/DopeyFaroffScreencast)

```js
// code for demo

const moment = require("moment");




const init = moment.utc('4:00', 'hh:mm');
const added = init.add(12, 'hours');


console.log(added);
console.log(added.format('hh:mm')); // 4:00
console.log(added.format('hh:mm a')); // 4:00 pm
console.log(added.format('HH:mm')); // 16:00
```

[moment format docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: you can include a tiny code snippet for better understanding of solution. also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: thank you for the link! I was not sure if the snippet allowed for importing moment so I went with a repl.it demo at first.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that yields an undefined answer, and the demo doesnt seem to be working either

Comment: Ahh ok its because, it needs to be `moment.utc('04:00', 'hh:mm').add(12, 'hours').format('HH:MM')` not `moment.utc('04:00', 'HH:MM').add(12, 'hours').format('HH:MM')` which is what i assumed you meant

Comment: Thank, you. Other than that point, your answer definitely should not have been downvoted lol

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ 
I think this might clear it up, as to why the demo is not working, I am not sure why repl.it would have two different outcomes, here's my output https://imgur.com/a/RzdpSoz hope that helps!